# How to prevent IOS from creating grey overlay?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, overlay

On IOS Devices like the Iphone 6s a bug occured and I don't know how to fix it. It occures on IOS only and not all the time. But on a site after a while when I try to click a navigation item the overlay appears when I click an element and vanishs when I remove the finger from the display. The overlay is a big square that doesn't fit to a specific element. It's 100% in width and is over the navigation and half the element below the navigation. Even when I try to click the element below the navigation the overlay appears.

I tried to fix it with:

```
html{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

But it didn't work. Anyone knows what causes that behavior, how to fix it or some hints for what to google?

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: @Chesswithsean: I'm afraid I can't since I'm not allowed to and I also couldn't provide a link because it's on a protected development server. But I bet it has something to do with the the grey Overlay created by IOS on touch events. But I don't know why -webkit-touch-callout:none;                
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;     
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-user-select:none; has no effect on it. There is no CSS rule that could overwrite that and those attributes are set to the html tag...